# Running hdfs -text command within mapper and using output

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Is there a way to run hadoop commands in the mapper?

For example I want to run

```
hdfs dfs -text /path/to/file
```

and I will use that output for my mapper logic. Or is there an alternative?

Such as running the command `hdfs dfs -text /path/to/file` as a subprocess with Java

Answer (score 1):

Better is to use the [Java HDFS API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) to open an HDFS file and read the contents into a variable that you can use.

For example:

```
InputStream is = FileSystem.get(yourConfigurationObject).open(new Path("/path/to/file"));
```

Comment: How could I perform an `-ls`? I want to store all the paths to a file. There is so much documentation. I am not sure where to look and how to look for it.

Comment: `fs.listStatus(new Path("/your/path"))` will return an array of `FileStatus`, from which each has a `getPath()` method.